# How does Luis pick up the van?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

During the scene where Luis is sat in the broken van and finds the remote for the building he uses the Hot Wheels rally case to get a different car. Naturally he chooses the sports hatchback with flames on it. He then enlarges that car moves to it, shrinks the van and drives off. When driving off all the doors appear to stay shut but when driving past the shrunken van it gets picked up by... ***something***.

You can view the scene below, the relevant section starting around 25 seconds in:

**How does he pick the van up?**

Comment: How does Luis pick up the van? *Very carefully.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you watch the YouTube video you linked to at 0.25x speed, it appears that he opens the door a crack and you can see his hand grab it. It's not conclusive though, and a re-watch of a higher frame rate media (i.e. Blu-Ray) at slow speed might prove to be more conclusive.

[image: Luis' blurry arm reaches out from the car's partially open door to pick up the shrunken van on the floor]

Comment: The timing! I just decided to watch it at 0.25 myself. Indeed it appears it is his hand. Extremely blurry though in my slower watch.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Good skills. I just grabbed exactly the same screen shot from here: http://www.watchframebyframe.com/watch/yt/Oq5U-tV0XA8

Comment: Okay not very carefully.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's blurry but that's a fingertip burn off manoeuvre if ever I saw one.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot he should definitely clean the wounded area, and very possibly apply some antiseptic.